# Input value clears when it component is hidden, but i dont want to do it. How can i fix it?

Tags: angular, angular-material

When i toggle visibility of my input child component his value clears and this is happen with all form components that i adding. How can i fix it?

**My input child component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>{{ title }}</mat-label>
  <input 
    [formControl]="control"
    [readonly]="!isVisible"
    [type]="type"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

**input.ts**

```
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() isVisible: boolean;
  @Input() control: FormControl;
  @Input() type: 'text' | 'number';
}
```

**Parent form component**

```
<div 
  [formGroup]="form">
  <app-input
    [control]="form.get('input')"
    [isVisible]="isVisible"
    type="text"
    title="Example title">
  </app-input>
</div>
```

**form component.ts**

```
export class IfaceFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() isVisible: boolean;

  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    input: this.fb.control('')
  });

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

}
```

**And my card component, where i import form component**

```
<mat-card>
   <div>
      <button (click)="toggleVisibiltyMode()">
        <mat-icon>mode_edit</mat-icon>
      </button>
  </div>
  <mat-card-content
    (click)="toggleViewMode()">
    <app-form *ngIf="!isCompactView" [isVisible]="isVisible"></app-form>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

**card component.ts**

```
export class WanCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() index: number;

  isVisible = false;
  isCompactView = false;

  toggleViewMode(): void {
    if (!this.isVisible) {
      this.isCompactView = !this.isCompactView;
    }
  }

  toggleVisibilityMode(): void {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
    if (this.isCompactView) {
      this.isCompactView = !this.isCompactView;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should show us some of your typescript as well. Or even better: put together a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just a guess: are you changing the value of `isCompactView` when toggling visibility? If so, app-form component will get destroyed and re-initialized every time (that's how `*ngIf` works). And that means a new form instance will get created every time you toggle visibility.

Comment: Fixed it by add `[ngClass]="{'display-none': isCompactView}"`